# Call to member data on userdata() on a non object

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am getting error

> Call to member data on userdata() on a non object

when i am setting the `Session` `$this->session->userdata('userName', $userName);`

**Login Controller**

```
<?php
    class loginController extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('session');
        }
        public function login() {   
            $this->load->View("template/header");
            $this->load->View("login_view");
        }
        public function AuthenticateUser() {
            //Is the UserName and Password values retrieved?
            if( isset( $_POST['userName'] ) && isset( $_POST['password'] ) ) {
                $this->load->library("UserFactory");

                $userName = addslashes($_POST['userName']);
                $password = addslashes($_POST['password']);

                //Get User details based on UserName and Password
                $data = array(
                    "users" => $this->userfactory->checkLogin($userName, $password)
                );
                if($data["users"] != null) {                    
                    $this->session->userdata('userName', $userName);
                }
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode( $data["users"] );
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Any Idea why this is happening ?

Comment: I don't know *why* but I would imagine the session object isn't being assigned to `$this->session`. I'd start by checking the constructors to see where the session is set to see if that gives any indication to the cause of the problem.

Comment: `set_userdata()` is being used to assign a var to the session. `userdata()` fetches the var from the session.

Comment: and when I load the library in Constructor. It says: `ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time`

Comment: `print_r($this->sesstion->userdata);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->session->userdata()
```

this **use to retrieve data** from session.

to **set session** use this

```
$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');
```

---

**Wrong Argument** on here

```
if($data["users"] != null) {                    
    $this->session->userdata('userName', $userName); # retrieving data
}
```

> You trying to access data from session without setting it
>
> Make sure **you have loaded** `$this->load->library('session');`

Comment: Still same Issue. and when I load the library in Constructor. It says: `ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time`

Comment: in here use `if(!empty($data["users"])`

Comment: Issue is: When I load the library `$this->load->library('session');` i constructor...Page shows error.`ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time`

Comment: Remove headers and check

Comment: Then it is fine and now not able to set session and facing the issue as mentioned in the query description.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 if($data["users"] != null) {                    
                    $this->session->userdata('userName', $userName);
                }
```

to

```
if($data["users"] != null) {                    
                        $this->session->set_userdata('userName', $userName);
                    }
```

More on session read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/session-handling-in-codeigniter/